# How to change the color of the tabs when clicked?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tabhost

```
  TabWidget tw = getTabWidget();

   for (int i = 0; i < tw.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = tw.getChildAt(i);


         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
    }
    tw.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B21206"));
```

There are two tabs in my activity. This code keeps the color of the first tab fixed to "RED" but does not make the second tab change to "RED" when clicked.
what changes should be done in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your tabactivity class.. it may helpful to you...

```
    for(int i = 0; i < getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        if(getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).isSelected())
        {
            //selected tab
            getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            //un-selected tabs
            getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xml bg selector for your task that is the better way of doing what you want.

of if you want in code  try this code

pass your tab host in settabColor(yourtabhost);

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
}
```

Comment: But will that not set the background for the whole page ?

Comment: First thing you want to change the activity background or tab background.